Cannot Get Git Submodule Due to Large File Size
We are trying to check out a submodule that has large files.
But on our build machines we are getting following issue.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 Recv failure: Connection was reset
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
We have following setting on .gitconfig
[http]
    proxy = http://url
    version = HTTP/1.1
[core]
    autocrlf = false
    compression = 0
    packedGitLimit = 4095m 
    packedGitWindowSize = 4095m 
[credential "http://url"]
    provider = generic
[filter "lfs"]
    clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
    smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
    process = git-lfs filter-process
    required = true
[safe]
    directory = SourcesDir
[pack] 
    deltaCacheSize = 8096m 
    packSizeLimit = 4095m 
    windowMemory = 8096m
    threads = 1

And still with those settings, we get git errors
following git submodule command is also failed with the same error.
git submodule update --init --force --recursive "SubmodulePath"

This submodule has large files.
what are the git settings we need, when we have large file submodules?
